# Keeping SQL Developer 4.0's Display Null Values during export

Tags: oracle, export, oracle-sqldeveloper

In SQL Developer 4.0 I have my Pref > Database > Advance > Display Null value as (null)  **Pretty sure that was the default value

My Query Results Report Grid show NULLs as (null).... Perfect!

When I export (or copy / paste)  to any formatted file type, tried them all, data that shows up as "(null)" in my Query Results Report Grid is now just a single space, " "...

I am trying to provide QA Testing reports to another department and although I could solve this writing SQL and formatting the output for every column, I would rather just export or copy /paste into excel to produce my proofs.

Is there a preference for this behavior I am not seeing?

Kurt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the SQL*Plus [`set null` command](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm#SQPUG092), which is one of many SQL Developer recognises.

When you set that and then run your query as a script (F5) the output appears in the Script Output window, and whatever text you specified appears instead of null. You can copy and paste from there but then you have to convert the text to data in Excel.

If you run your query as a statement (Ctrl-Enter) then the output in the Query Result window shows the value you set in the preferences, *not* what you specified with `set null`. However, when you right-click and export to CSV, the export file *does* use the `set null` string.

For example, if you set the null handling in your worksheet:

```
set null "NULL"
```

and then run a query as a script:

```
select 1 as id, null as value from dual;
```

the Script Output window shows:

```
        ID VALUE
---------- -----
         1 NULL
```

If you run the query as a statement then the Query Result window shows the `(null)` from preferences rather then `NULL`:

[image]

But when you right-click and export as CSV, the file produced contains:

```
"ID","VALUE"
1,NULL
```

If you do `set null "(null)"` so that value matches the display preference then you won't notice the difference, of course.